# Color Management - ACES / OCIO config Mismatch between Renderman and Redshift in Blender 2.93.4

Tags: rendering, color, color-management, renderman-render-engine

This is going to be a somewhat complicated question.

I am using Blender 2.93.4 and I have both **Renderman** and **Redshift** installed. After installing both, I ran into a strange bug where Redshift was trying to load the Renderman ocio config and crashing.

Here's a screenshot of Redshift's log that shows what I mean (note the highlighted lines):

[image: Redshift Log]

I posted a topic describing the problem on the Redshift forum here:

https://redshift.maxon.net/topic/38892/redshift-for-blender-is-not-rendering

The final solution that worked was adding the following environment variable to my system:

```
OCIO = C:\ProgramData\Redshift\Plugins\Blender\2.93.0\ocio\config.ocio
```

As soon as I added this variable both Redshift and Renderman stopped crashing and played nice with each other.

However, now I'm worried about one thing. Despite Renderman working now, I'm not sure if it's using its own ocio config or the Redshift config I supplied in my environment variable.

Redshift has **OCIO v2, ACES Built-in.**
Renderman has **ACES-1.2, Filmic Blender, and Basic.**

All are found here:

```
C:\Program Files\Pixar\RenderManProServer-24.1\lib\ocio\
C:\ProgramData\Redshift\Plugins\Blender\2.93.0\ocio\
```

Final Questions:

---

1. Is there a way to tell what ACES config Renderman is using?
2. If Renderman is indeed using the Redshift ACES 2.0 config, are there any drawbacks?
3. Does Renderman prioritize the system OCIO environment variable over it's own ACES config?

---

Renderman seems to be working fine, but I really want to leverage the benefits of ACES, and I am going crazy properly configuring all of this in Blender.

Final note: I tried the .bat file method and it didn't work at all for some reason. Just stating this because I'm pretty sure someone's going to suggest it.

I would greatly, greatly appreciate any kind of help!

Jay

Answer (score 2):

> If Renderman is indeed using the Redshift ACES 2.0 config, are there any drawbacks?

Ain’t no such thing. There’s only ACES 1.X currently.

> Does Renderman prioritize the system OCIO environment variable over it's own ACES config?

Easy to tell if the environment variable is working, as usually there’s a transform that isn’t in another config. That said, assuming things are OpenColorIO compliant, the environment variable will be honoured if launched from the same instance.